# Show search option for select in react-awesome-query-builder

Tags: reactjs, select, query-builder

I am using `react-awesome-query-builder` for building the query, But I am not able to search the values in the select box. Getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. I have tried passing values in lower case but no luck.
I am using this configuration in react application
https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder#usage. I am new to `react-awesome-query-builder` please help me. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## The value you pass is undefined

The value you are passing down is undefined. It has nothing to do with `toLowerCase`. This is just a string method that is being fired by the search function. But because your search is undefined it throws an error.

Can't give you code because you didn't supply any. But that's the reason you're getting an error.

Comment: I am using this code https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder#usage.
```
 color: {
        label: 'Color',
        type: 'select',
        valueSources: ['value'],
        listValues: [
          { value: 'yellow', title: 'Yellow' },
          { value: 'green', title: 'Green' },
          { value: 'orange', title: 'Orange' }
        ],
    },
```

Comment: @SarikaJamdade you should read the guidelines, never base your question off a link. You don't need to add all your code but the question should be understandable and fixable with just the stuff that we can see here on SO. What happens in 4 years when your link is broken? the question is useless to others coming up on the same issues